# Mod_Rewrite Rules for my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to create a redirect in htaccess for urls that are like this:

https://example.com/firstnamelastname?mv=0 or https://example.com/firstnamelastname?mv=2

and also https://example.com/firstnamelastname

To redirect to https://firstnamelastname.example.com

Where firstnamelastname can be a-z and 0-9 only. mv=0 to 4.

Comment: Does the site `https://firstnamelastname.example.com` actually exist?

Comment: Also, you say "mv=1 to 4" yet in your first example you have mv=0

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I wanted to say 0-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a redirect, then you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^mv=[0-4]$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ https://$1.example.com/? [L,R]
```

Comment: This works but I forgot to mention it should also redirect just subdirectory to the subdomain. ie. https://example.com/firstnamelastname to https://firstnamelastname.example.com